# sweet.js: transforming occurrences of a repeated token

Tags: sweet.js

I want to define a sweet macro that transforms

```
{ a, b } # o
```

into

```
{ o.a, o.b }
```

My current attempt is

```
macro (#) {  
  case infix { { $prop:ident (,) ... } | _ $o } => {
    return #{ { $prop: $o.$prop (,) ... } }
  }
}
```

However, this give me

```
SyntaxError: [patterns] Ellipses level does not match in the template
```

I suspect I don't really understand how `...` works, and may need to somehow loop over the values of `$prop` and build syntax objects for each and somehow concatenate them, but I'm at a loss as to how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the syntax expander thinks you're trying to expand `$o.$prop` instead of `$prop: $o.$prop`. Here's the solution:

```
macro (#) {  
  rule infix { { $prop:ident (,) ... } | $o:ident } => {
    { $($prop: $o.$prop) (,) ... }
  }
}
```

Notice that I placed the unit of code in a `$()` block of its own to disambiguate the ellipse expansion.

Example: `var x = { a, b } # o;` becomes `var x = { a: o.a, b: o.b };`.